# How split comma in AJAX data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use this script to send if a checkbox is checked or unchecked:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.model').click(function() {
    var formData = $('#myForm').serialize();
    console.log('Posting the following: ', formData);
    
 // send ajax
 $.ajax({
                url: 'av_check.php', // url where to submit the request
                type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
                dataType : 'json', // data type
                data : $("#myForm").serializeArray(), // post data || get data
                success : function(result, status, xhr) {
                  

                    alert("response was "+result);
                    // you can see the result from the console
                    // tab of the developer tools
                    console.log(result);

                },
                error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                }
            
            })
        });
    });

</script>
```

And this is for my checkboxes:

```
<input id="model" name="model[]" class="model" type="checkbox" value="VARIABLE">
```

And my PHP:

```
echo json_encode($_POST['model']);
```

When multiple checkboxes are checked, then I get:

response was

> 08:15,08:30,08:45

(the values of the checkboxes are different times)

So far so good, but I want to handle this data on the PHP page.
So I tried `$str_arr = explode (",", $_POST['model']);` to split the values, but it doesn't seem to work.

So I searched for how to handle this data, but I can't seem to find it. Maybe I am not using the right terms, but is there anybody who knows how to handle this data?

Comment: Looks like `$_POST['model']` is an array of values, so you can use something like `foreach($_POST['model'] as $model)`

Comment: Why don't you send `formData` (which you've already serialized using `serialize()` instead of serializing the form again, but that time using `serializeArray()`? It's also unclear what you mean by _"it doesn't seem to work"_. When? Where? How?

Answer (score 0):

I am entireley rewriting my response here. Lesson learned, don't try to help on NYE.

Update your HTML page to something like this

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="myForm">
<input id="model" name="model[]" class="model" type="checkbox" value="value1">
<input id="model1" name="model[]" class="model" type="checkbox" value="value2">
<input id="model2" name="model[]" class="model" type="checkbox" value="value3">
<input id="model3" name="model[]" class="model" type="checkbox" value="value4">
<input id="model4" name="model[]" class="model" type="checkbox" value="value5">
<button type="button" id="submit" onClick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm(){
    var myData = $('#myForm').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "av_check.php",
        data: myData,
        success: function (data) {   // success callback function
            console.log(data)
        }
    });

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your PHP, simply reference the $_GET['model'] variable

PHP file - av_check.php

```
<?php
print_r($_GET['model']);
?>
```

If you submit that, the console will output the value of the checked checkboxes.

Output:
Array
(
[0] => value1
[1] => value2
)

Comment: Wouldn't `.serializeArray()` post the whole form as JSON `[{"name": "input-name", "value": "input-value"}, ...]` and so on? In that case, there wouldn't be any `$_POST['model']` set at all? I've never used `serializeArray()`, but based on the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/serializearray/

Comment: I posted a more complete (an also corrected) example

Comment: _"using serialize or serialize array would make it available via $_GET instead"_ - No, serialize and serializeArray is just methods of serializing the data. It won't decide what HTTP method to use. The OP has `type: 'POST'` in their Ajax request, which sets it as a POST request. The thing is that if you post data in JSON format, the `$_POST` variable won't be populated and you will need to fetch and parse the POST body manually. `serialize()` converts the form elements into a www-form-urlencoded format, while `serializeArray()` (according to the docs) converts it into JSON.